# Brackets make a vector different. How exactly is vector expression evaluated?

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have a data frame as follows:

```
planets               type diameter rotation rings
Mercury Terrestrial planet    0.382    58.64 FALSE 
Venus   Terrestrial planet    0.949  -243.02 FALSE 
Earth   Terrestrial planet    1.000     1.00 FALSE 
Mars    Terrestrial planet    0.532     1.03 FALSE
Jupiter          Gas giant   11.209     0.41 TRUE
Saturn          Gas giant     9.449     0.43 TRUE
Uranus          Gas giant     4.007    -0.72 TRUE
Neptune          Gas giant    3.883     0.67  TRUE
```

I wanted to select last 3 rows:

`planets_df[nrow(planets_df)-3:nrow(planets_df),]`

However, I've got something I didn't expect:

```
planets          type                  diameter rotation rings
Jupiter          Gas giant            11.209     0.41  TRUE
Mars             Terrestrial planet    0.532     1.03 FALSE
Earth            Terrestrial planet    1.000     1.00 FALSE
Venus            Terrestrial planet    0.949  -243.02 FALSE
Mercury          Terrestrial planet    0.382    58.64 FALSE
```

With trial and error method, I've learned that

```
> (nrow(planets_df)-3):nrow(planets_df)
[1] 5 6 7 8
```

and

```
> nrow(planets_df)-3:nrow(planets_df)
[1] 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

How does exactly R evaluate **`:`** statement (with reference to brackets)?

Comment: You can find the answer to this [under "Operator Syntax and Precedence"](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html). The "-" is a binary subtract, so it has a lower order of precedence than `:`, hence the need for brackets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subsetting R with dynamic variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335734/subsetting-r-with-dynamic-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon operator will take precedence over the arithmetic operations. It is always best to experiment with examples to internalize the logic:

```
2*2:6-1
```

What answer should we expect? Some would say `4 5`. The thinking is that it will simplify to `2*2=4` and `6-1=5`, therefore `4:5`.

```
2*2:6-1
[1]  3  5  7  9 11
```

This answer will surprise anyone who hasn't considered the order of operations in play. The expression `2*2:6-1` is simplified differently. The sequence `2:6` is carried out first, then the multiplication, and finally the addition. We could write it out as `2 * (2 3 4 5 6)`, which is `4 6 8 10 12` and subtract `1` from that to get `3 5 7 9 11`.

By grouping with parantheses we can control the order of operations as we would do similarly in basic arithmetic to get the answer that we first expected.

```
(2*2):(6-1)
[1] 4 5
```

You can apply this reasoning to your example to investigate the seemingly odd behavior of the `:` operator.

Now that you know the secret codes, what should we expect from `(2*2):6-1`?

Answer (score 2):

The colon `:` separates the starting point from the end point of a sequence. It is treated with higher priority than the `+` or `-` operator.
Therefore,

```
nrow(planets_df)-3:nrow(planets_df)
```

is equal to

```
nrow(planets_df) - (3:nrow(planets_df))
```

If you want to have the last three entries using this syntax, you need to put the entire expression that defines the start of the sequence into brackets:

```
planets_df[(nrow(planets_df)-3):nrow(planets_df),]
```

Answer (score 1):

`nrow(planets_df)-3:nrow(planets_df)` is being evaluated as 8 - (3:8) or

(8-3) (8-4) (8-5) (8-6) (8-7) (8-8) = 5 4 3 2 1 0

For future reference if you want the last few rows, use `tail(planets_df, 3)`