# Subsetting R with dynamic variables

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the below example code. I have a dataframe ts which has 16 rows. when I subset with actual numbers it works fine but when I subset with calculated numbers why is my code behaving weirdly ?

Can anyone please explain me what's wrong in this?

**Case1:**

```
> a
[1] 12
> c
[1] 16

> ts$trend[13:16]
[1] 21.36926 21.48654 21.60383 21.72111

> ts$trend[a+1:c]
 [1] 21.36926 21.48654 21.60383 21.72111       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
[13]       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

**Case 2:**

```
> b
[1] 4
> temp[1: 8]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
> temp[1: b+b]
[1] 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Try with using brackets `(a+1):c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of operator precedence.  It can be avoided by using brackets

```
temp[1:(b+b)]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

---

If we check the problem in OP's code

```
1:b
#[1] 1 2 3 4

(1:b) + b
#[1] 5 6 7 8
```

So, the operator precedence happens here by evaluating 1:b followed by adding the b.

This is well described in `?Syntax`

> :: ::: access variables in a namespace 
>   $ @ component / slot
>   extraction  [ [[ indexing 
>   ^ exponentiation (right to left) 
>   - + unary minus and plus
>   : sequence operator  %any% special operators (including %% and %/%) 
>   * / multiply, divide 
>   + - (binary) add, subtract
>    < > <= >= == != ordering and comparison
>    ! negation
>    & && and
>    | || or 
>    ~ as in formulae 
>   -> ->> rightwards assignment 
>    <- <<- assignment (right to left) 
>   = assignment (right to left)
>   ? help (unary and binary)

#### data

```
temp <- 1:10
b <- 4
```

Answer (score 5):

R doesn't care about they way you space expressions. Things are evaluated according to a strict precedence scheme. Things in parentheses are done first. So:

```
> 1: b+b
[1] 5 6 7 8
```

because addition has lower precedence than ":". The `1:b` is evaluated first, and then `b` is added. So you get:

```
> (1:b)+b
[1] 5 6 7 8
```

If you want the alternative, parenthesise things:

```
> 1:(b+b)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I'd suggest you also parenthesise `(1+b):b` if that is ever what you want - the brackets make no difference but they aid readability for anyone who forgets the precedence rules.